# What is a cathode and an anode in general sense

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, batteries

i am totally confused and not able to understand the difference between cathode and anode

Cathode is defined as reduction point but why is its sign -ve in a terminal and different in a battery

Anode is oxidation point why is its sign +ve in a termianl and different in a battery

Is there no general method so that i can figure out what a cathode and anode is in a circuit

And what is the main idea behind the sign givem to them

Answer (score -1):

An electrode is labelled -ve when it "loses" electrons, and +ve when it "gains" electrons. This is why the - and + are switched in a battery compared to say, electrolysis.